# Multi value form questions

Tags: ms-access

How do I display a multi value field on a form in a way. That all the various values can be represented individually on a form?

Example. I have a field on the table called toppings. Under toppings I have cheese,tomato,pepperoni and section to write any other toppings that comes to mind.

The multi value field will be toppings(cheese,tomato,pepperoni and section to write any other toppings that comes to mind.)

Now on the form I want all the list to have there own individual check boxes.

Comment: I don't mean this in an offensive tone but it sounds like a bad database design. They should have been True/False fields in a table, and not a multi value field.

Comment: I had that variation also.The problem was when it came to the reporting. I need to be able to print the content in each field. But as the form grew. The number of true and false field grew.

Comment: So for example I have over 15 toppings. And I need to join them all into 1 field. In the table I have 15 check-box fields. How do I translate them to one field?

Comment: Well, I guess I could see why you changed it to a multi-value field in that aspect. I had misunderstood how you were using the options. Have you thought about using a Combobox or some sort of control that displays them as a list? See [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-use-the-new-multivalue-field-in-access-2007-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was not too clear on the question. But I found the solution. I used a list box.